# Perl regex match longest sequence

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like below

```
atom:link[@me="samiron" and @test1="t1" and @test2="t2"]
```

and I need a regular expression which will generate the following back references

```
#I would prefer to have
$1 = @test1
$2 = t1
$3 = @test2
$4 = t2

#Or at least. I will break these up in parts later on.
$1 = @test1="t1"
$2 = @test2="t2"
```

I've tried something like `( and [@\w]+=["\w]+)*\]` which returns only last match `and @test2="t2"`. Completely out of ideas. Any help?

**Edit:**
actually the number of `@test1="t1"` pattern is not fixed. And the regex must fit the situation. Thnx @Pietzcker.

Comment: Do you know the number of parameters beforehand (it doesn't seem so, and in that case, you can't do it with backreferences)? Also, why don't you want `@me` and `samiron` to be matched?

Comment: oh yes.. actually the number of `@test1="t1"` pattern is not fixed. thnx for asking the question.. And i need the regex must fit this situation. I will add this in my question.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: well in the real scenario there are some different stuffs in the place of `@me="samiron"` i dont need that part. Or i can say, i need to skip the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you hash which maps "@test1" => "t1" and so on:

```
my %matches = ($str =~ /and (\@\w+)="(\w+)"/g);
```

Explanation: /g global match will give you an array of matches like
"@test1", "t1", "@test2", "t2", ...

When hash %matches is assigned to this array, perl will automatically convert array to hash by treating it as key-value pairs.
As a result, hash %matches will contain what are you looking for in nice hash format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
my $text = 'atom:link[@me="samiron" and @test1="t1" and @test2="t2"]';
my @results;
while ($text =~ m/and (@\w+)="(\w+)"/g) {
  push @results, $1, $2;
}
print Dumper \@results;
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '@me',
          'samiron',
          '@test1',
          't1',
          '@test2',
          't2'
        ];
```

Comment: Nops, he doesn't want '@me' and 'samiron' to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a repeating capturing group, each new match will overwrite any previous match.

So you can only do a "find all" with a regex like

```
@result = $subject =~ m/(?<= and )([@\w]+)=(["\w]+)(?= and |\])/g;
```

to get an array of all matches.

Comment: `[@\w]+` would also match words that dont start with `@`..i guess from the Q the word always start from `@`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@result = $s =~ /(@(?!me).*?)="(.*?)"/g;
foreach (@result){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
@test1
t1
@test2
t2
```